# run two ongoing processes on startup with one that needs initialization time

Tags: bash, suspend, cron

I'd like to record start recording utility consumption right at startup but I can't find the right combo of operators, pipes, and sleep commands to enter into crontab -e . I think my smartest attempt would be

`@reboot rtl_tcp || sleep 4 || ./go/bin/rtlamr -logfile=/home/ubuntu/log.json`

Shouldn't this start start rtl_tcp, wait a few seconds, then start logging with rtlamr?

Answer (score 1):

An easier way would be to put your startup commands in a script, and invoke that:

```
# You could put the file in any other directory that is mounted
# early in boot time (not your HOME directory)
cat >>/var/local/foo <<EOF
#!/bin/bash
# Suggestion: use absolute path: /usr/local/bin/rtl_tcp
rtl_tcp
sleep 4
# Warning - MUST specify absolute path! "." is probably "/" here.
./go/bin/rtlamr -logfile=/home/ubuntu/log.json
EOF
chmod +x /var/local/foo
```

and, in your `crontab`

```
@reboot /var/local/foo
```

Your expression with the `||`s requires that `rtl_tcp` and `sleep 4` each return a status of `0` so the next step will be evaluated.

Answer (score 0):

Immediately I'm noticing that your command

```
@reboot rtl_tcp || sleep 4 || ./go/bin/rtlamr -logfile=/home/ubuntu/log.json
```

uses an OR list operator (the `||` symbols). It does this:

> An OR list has the form
>
> ```
> command1 || command2
> ```
>
> command2  is  executed  if  and  only if command1 returns a non-zero exit status.

So the `sleep 4` command will only be run if `rtl_tcp` *fails*, and the last (logging) command only starts if `sleep` fails.

Try using the AND list operator `&&`, it only runs the next command if the previous one succeeds.

And see `man bash` for more info on them (Shell Grammar -> Lists).